# Go destructors?

Tags: go

I know there are no destructors in Go since technically there are no classes. As such, I use `initClass` to perform the same functions as a constructor. However, is there any way to create something to mimic a destructor in the event of a termination, for the use of, say, closing files? Right now I just call `defer deinitClass`, but this is rather hackish and I think a poor design. What would be the proper way?

Comment: A minor heads-up: having the word "class" in the name of a "constructor" and "destructor" functions is confusing and might indicate that you maintain a somewhat wrong mental model about this stuff: such functions initialize/deinitialize *instances* of a type (well, Go has no classes, but classes in C++-like PLs are types), that is, concrete variables which have a particular type. They don't initialize/deinitialize a type itself. Basically that's why "constructor" functions are typically called `New()` or `NewWhatever()` in Go: they give you a new initialized *value.*

Comment: You might find [this](https://blog.golang.org/package-names) to be of particular interest with regard to naming packages, types and functions in well-written Go code. Be sure to also check out the section titled "Further reading" there.

Comment: @kostix the use of initClass and deinitClass were just generic I was just using the names to show what I was doing. I created a struct then called initStructName to do some fancy things then under that I added defer deinitStructName, to close files, and properly clean up etc.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In the Go ecosystem, there exists a ubiquitous idiom for dealing with objects which wrap precious (and/or external) resources: a special method designated for freeing that resource, called *explicitly* — typically via the `defer` mechanism.

This special method is typically named `Close()`, and the user of the object has to call it explicitly when they're done with the resource the object represents. The `io` standard package does even have a special interface, [`io.Closer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Closer), declaring that single method.  Objects implementing I/O on various resources such as TCP sockets, UDP endpoints and files all satisfy `io.Closer`, and are expected to be explicitly `Close`d after use.

Calling such a cleanup method is typically done via the `defer` mechanism which guarantees the method will run no matter if some code which executes after resource acquisition will `panic()` or not.

You might also notice that not having implicit "destructors" quite balances not having implicit "constructors" in Go.  This actually has nothing to do with not having "classes" in Go: the language designers just avoid *magic* as much as practically possible.

---

Note that Go's approach to this problem might *appear* to be somewhat low-tech but in fact it's the only workable solution for the runtime featuring garbage-collection.  In a language with objects but without GC, say C++, destructing an object is a well-defined operation because an object is destroyed either when it goes out of scope or when `delete` is called on its memory block.  In a runtime with GC, the object will be destroyed at some mostly indeterminate point in the future by the GC scan, and *may not be destroyed at all.*  So if the object wraps some precious resource, that resource might get reclaimed way past the moment in time the last live reference to the enclosing object was lost, and it might even not get reclaimed at all—as has been well explained by @twotwotwo in their respective answer.

Another interesting aspect to consider is that the Go's GC is fully concurrent (with the regular program execution). This means a GC thread which is about to collect a dead object might (and usually will) be not the thread(s) which executed that object's code when it was alive. In turn, this means that if the Go types could have destructors then the programmer would need to make sure whatever code the destructor executes is properly synchronized with the rest of the program—if the object's state affects some data structures external to it. This actually might force the programmer to add such synchronization even if the object does not need it for its normal operation (and most objects fall into such category). And think about what happens of those exernal data strucrures happened to be destroyed before the object's destructor was called (the GC collects dead objects in a non-deterministic way). In other words, it's much easier to control — and to reason about — object destruction when it is explicitly coded into the program's flow: both for specifying when the object has to be destroyed, and for guaranteeing proper ordering of its destruction with regard to destroying of the data structures external to it.

If you're familiar with .NET, it deals with resource cleanup in a way which resembles that of Go quite closely: your objects which wrap some precious resource have to implement the `IDisposable` interface, and a method, `Dispose()`, exported by that interface, must be called explicitly when you're done with such an object.  C# provides some syntactic sugar for this use case via the `using` statement which makes the compiler arrange for calling `Dispose()` on the object when it goes out of the scope declared by the said statement.  In Go, you'll typically `defer` calls to cleanup methods.

---

One more note of caution.  Go wants you to treat errors very seriously (unlike most mainstream programming language with their ["just throw an exception and don't give a fsck about what happens due to it elsewhere and what state the program will be in" attitude](http://250bpm.com/blog:4)) and so you might consider checking error returns of at least *some* calls to cleanup methods.

A good example is instances of the `os.File` type representing files on a filesystem.  The fun stuff is that calling `Close()` on an open file *might* fail due to legitimate reasons, and if you were *writing* to that file this might indicate that not all the data you wrote to that file had actually landed in it *on the file system.*  For an explanation, please read the "Notes" section in the [`close(2)` manual](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close).

In other words, just doing something like

```
fd, err := os.Open("foo.txt")
defer fd.Close()
```

is okay for read-only files in the 99.9% of cases, but for files opening for writing, you might want to implement more involved error checking and some strategy for dealing with them (mere reporting, wait-then-retry, ask-then-maybe-retry or whatever).

Comment: Great answer, for explaining what you should do instead. The ZeroMQ link is cool too--personally found that error returns are great when you need to fully understand what happens down every error path.

Comment: That link to the ZMQ author comparing C and C++ is pretty horrible. I fail to see any actual argument (Note: I don't rule out that there were places in ZMQ where use of exceptions was a bad choice!) supporting the claims. I'd rather say that the author builds a few strawmen and then takes them down. For example, saying C++ is object oriented. For example, ignoring move semantics. @kostix, your answer is good, but it would be better off without this link.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, unfortunately, I know of no other available material which would explicate the problems with exceptions as good as that one, so I'm inclined to let it stay for exactly _that_ reason. Your comment might serve well as a sort of "caveat emptor" attached to that link ;-)

Comment: Some articles on the @eli-bendersky's personal site come close but not quite. I like [this one](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/c-raii-without-exceptions/) for instance.

Answer (score 26):

[`runtime.SetFinalizer(ptr, finalizerFunc)`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetFinalizer) sets a finalizer--not a destructor but another mechanism to maybe eventually free up resources. Read the documentation there for details, including downsides. They might not run until long after the object is actually unreachable, and they might not run at all if the program exits first. They also postpone freeing memory for another GC cycle.

If you're acquiring some limited resource that doesn't already have a finalizer, and the program would eventually be unable to continue if it kept leaking, you should consider setting a finalizer. It can mitigate leaks. Unreachable files and network connections are already cleaned up by finalizers in the stdlib, so it's only other sorts of resources where custom ones can be useful. The most obvious class is system resources you acquire through `syscall` or `cgo`, but I can imagine others.

Finalizers can help get a resource freed eventually even if the code using it omits a `Close()` or similar cleanup, but they're too unpredictable to be the main way to free resources. They don't run until GC does. Because the program could exit before next GC, you can't rely on them for things that must be done, like flushing buffered output to the filesystem. If GC *does* happen, it might not happen soon enough: if a finalizer is responsible for closing network connections, maybe a remote host hits its limit on open connections to you before GC, or your process hits its file-descriptor limit, or you run out of [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port), or something else. So it's much better to `defer` and do cleanup *right when it's necessary* than to use a finalizer and hope it's done soon enough.

You don't see many `SetFinalizer` calls in everyday Go programming, partly because the most important ones are in the standard library and mostly because of their limited range of applicability in general.

In short, finalizers can help by freeing forgotten resources in long-running programs, but because not much about their behavior is guaranteed, they aren't fit to be your main resource-management mechanism.

Comment: `SetFinalizer` is the only method available to free cgo resources in line with when their golang dependancies are garbage collected - its very useful for c wrappers, especially when the C objects have restrictions on when they can be freed relative to one another.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Actually, this is the most helpful answer. I'm planning to use it in order to protect files from being cleaned-up, while they are still referenced/reachable from code (using stored filename, not opened file). And, references to those files (filenames) have unpredictable life-cycle.

Comment: @kravemir Thanks for the appreciation! This may be inapplicable to your situation or too late to be useful, but wanted to note that at least on Linux, you can keep an open filehandle pointing at a deleted file. Then after all the filehandles are closed (explicitly or by finalizers or shutdown of the program), the OS will actually free the space on disk. Depending on the details of what you're doing, that might allow you to have automatic file cleanup without much implementation work on the Go side.

Answer (score 9):

There are Finalizers in Go. I wrote a little [blog post](http://lk4d4.darth.io/posts/finalizers/) about it. They are even used for closing files in the standard library as you can see [here](https://golang.org/src/os/file_unix.go#L55).
However, I think using defer is more preferable because it's more readable and less magical.

Comment: If you're acquiring some limited resource that doesn't already have a finalizer, and the program would eventually be unable to continue if it kept leaking, you should consider setting a finalizer. At the same time, since they don't run until GC does, it's better to `defer` and free the resources immediately than rely on finalizers. In other words, finalizers might be a useful insurance policy against otherwise-hard-to-plug leaks, but they aren't good as your main resource-management mechanism.

Comment: @twotwotwo please make a proper answer out of it. The comment might not be noticed, and stating loud and clear that finalizers should never ever be used and an explicit way for the user to signal "I'm done with this object" must be implemented and documented instead.

Comment: Good call @kostix, fleshed that out and added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar challenge, and decided to develop my own solution to it, called `ex.Terminator`: https://github.com/Seb-C/ex

What it does is provide the same deferring mechanism of the `defer` keyword, but applied to the lifecycle of an object.

While this does not fully automate the destruction, it helped my use case a lot by keeping the close operations more consistent and maintainable.

Here is an example of how it works - and what your code might look like by using it:

```
type FileRepository struct {
    ex.Terminator
    file *os.File
}

func NewFileRepository() (fileRepo *FileRepository, err error) {
    fileRepo = &FileRepository{}

    fileRepo.file, err = os.Create("data.json")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fileRepo.Defer(fileRepo.file.Close)

    fileRepo.Defer(func() error {
        fmt.Println("closing FileRepository")
        return nil
    })

    return fileRepo, nil
}

type DBRepository struct {
    ex.Terminator
    db *sql.DB
}

func NewDBRepository() (dbRepo *DBRepository, err error) {
    dbRepo = &DBRepository{}

    dbRepo.db, err = sql.Open("sqlite3", ":memory:")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    dbRepo.Defer(dbRepo.db.Close)

    dbRepo.Defer(func() error {
        fmt.Println("closing DBRepository")
        return nil
    })

    return dbRepo, nil
}

type Service struct {
    ex.Terminator
    fileRepo *FileRepository
    dbRepo   *DBRepository
}

func NewService() (service *Service, err error) {
    service = &Service{}

    service.fileRepo, err = NewFileRepository()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    service.Defer(service.fileRepo.Close)

    service.dbRepo, err = NewDBRepository()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    service.Defer(service.dbRepo.Close)

    return service, nil
}

func main() {
    service, err := NewService()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer service.Close()

    // Output:
    // "closing DBRepository"
    // "closing FileRepository"
}
```