# golang struct default value using bson

Tags: go

I looking return default value for new struct, without value, this is my current struct :

```
// Campaign represents a email campaign
type Campaign struct {
    ID             bson.ObjectId   `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    CampaignName   string          `json:"campaign_name" bson:"campaign_name"`
    FromName       []string        `json:"from_name" bson:"from_name"`
    FromEmail      string          `json:"from_email" bson:"from_email"`
    ReplyEmail     string          `json:"reply_email" bson:"reply_email"`
    Subject        []string        `json:"subject" bson:"subject"`
    BodyText       string          `json:"body_text" bson:"body_text"`
    BodyHTML       string          `json:"body_html" bson:"body_html"`
    SMTPList       bson.ObjectId `json:"smtp_list" bson:"smtp_list"`
    EmailList      bson.ObjectId `json:"email_list" bson:"email_list"`
    DateCreated    time.Time       `json:"date_created" bson:"date_created"`
    DateUpdated    time.Time       `json:"date_updated" bson:"date_updated"`
    DateSendFinish time.Time       `json:"date_send_finish" bson:"date_send_finish"`
    OwnerID        bson.ObjectId   `json:"owner_id" bson:"owner_id"`
    Opens          int             `json:"opens" bson:"opens"`
    Clicks         int             `json:"clicks" bson:"clicks"`
    Status         string          `json:"status" bson:"status"`
}
```

I want to return Status = "draft"
How i can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find another post

> One possible idea is to write separate constructor function

```
// Something is the structure we work with
type Something struct {
     Text string 
     DefaultText string 
} 

// NewSomething create new instance of Something
func NewSomething(text string) Something {
   something := Something{}
   something.Text = text
   something.DefaultText = "default text"
   return something
}
```

> Force a method to get the struct (the constructor way).
>
> A good design is to make your type unexported, but provide an exported
> constructor function like NewMyType() in which you can properly
> initialize your struct / type. Also return an interface type and not a
> concrete type, and the interface should contain everything others want
> to do with your value. And your concrete type must implement that
> interface of course.
>
> This can be done by simply make the type itself unexported. You can
> export the function NewSomething and even the fields Text and
> DefaultText, but just don't export the struct type something
>
> Another way to customize it for you own module is by using a [Config
> struct to set default values](https://web.archive.org/web/20160818125551/https://joneisen.tumblr.com/post/53695478114/golang-and-default-values) (Option 5 in the link) Not a good way
> though.

[Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37521991)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Campaign represents a email campaign
type Campaign struct {
    ID             bson.ObjectId   `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    CampaignName   string          `json:"campaign_name" bson:"campaign_name"`
    FromName       []string        `json:"from_name" bson:"from_name"`
    FromEmail      string          `json:"from_email" bson:"from_email"`
    ReplyEmail     string          `json:"reply_email" bson:"reply_email"`
    Subject        []string        `json:"subject" bson:"subject"`
    BodyText       string          `json:"body_text" bson:"body_text"`
    BodyHTML       string          `json:"body_html" bson:"body_html"`
    SMTPList       bson.ObjectId `json:"smtp_list" bson:"smtp_list"`
    EmailList      bson.ObjectId `json:"email_list" bson:"email_list"`
    DateCreated    time.Time       `json:"date_created" bson:"date_created"`
    DateUpdated    time.Time       `json:"date_updated" bson:"date_updated"`
    DateSendFinish time.Time       `json:"date_send_finish" bson:"date_send_finish"`
    OwnerID        bson.ObjectId   `json:"owner_id" bson:"owner_id"`
    Opens          int             `json:"opens" bson:"opens"`
    Clicks         int             `json:"clicks" bson:"clicks"`
    Status         string          `json:"status" bson:"status"`
}
```

Simply You can do like this

```
campaign.Status = "draft"
```

or maybe if you want sometype of condition

```
if true {
campaign.Status = "draft"
} else {
campaign.Status = "sent"
}
```