# How can I set null value as default to struct

Tags: go, struct

I am trying to add null value as default to struct. Is there any way to add null as default?

```
type Values struct {
    FirstValue string `default:"My First Value"`
    SecondValue string `default:nil` // something like that
}
```

Comment: Why do you think there is a "default value", and what do you think `nil` means in a variable of type `string`?

Comment: A `string` can't be `nil`. go is a statically typed language.

Comment: brother @torek I asked is there any way? I'm new in GO and I'm not sure about default value or assigning nil value to string. That's I'm asking is there any way?

Comment: I was wondering because not that many languages even have a concept of "default value": there might be default *constructors* but not default *values* and you'd have to write a constructor function. Which you can do in Go, it's just not going to be *called* automatically. Meanwhile, strings are counted-byte-sequences, so what would a nil string *be?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Go you can't access uninitialized memory. If you don't provide an initial value in a variable declaration, the variable will be initialized to the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of its type automatically.

Moreover, you can't define default values for struct fields. Unless given with a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), all fields will get their zero values.

Zero value of the `string` type is the empty string `""`. If you need to store the null value, use a pointer to `string`. Zero value for pointers is `nil`:

```
type Values struct {
    FirstValue  string
    SecondValue *string
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Strings in Go cannot be `nil`. Their zero value is just an empty string - `""`.

See https://tour.golang.org/basics/12

Also, there is no `default` tag in Go as each type has a zero value which is used as a "default". But, there are patterns in Go that allow you to set different "default" values, see [How to set default values in Go structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135193/how-to-set-default-values-in-go-structs).

Comment: Are we just going to ignore the fact that there is no `default` tag then?

Comment: brother @super I'm new in go and I didn't knew about that. Is there any other way or other data type to use string and nil at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this way :)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Hoho struct {
    Name *string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    var nama string = "ganang"
    var h Hoho
    h.Name = NullString(nama)

    wo, _ := json.Marshal(h)
    fmt.Print(string(wo))
}

func NullString(v string) *string {
    if v == "" {
        return nil
    }

    return &v
}
```