# Bug or Feature? Garbage Collection related to 'range' and 'channel' in Golang

Tags: go, garbage-collection

```
package main

import (
   "sync"
   "runtime"
)

type S struct {
   chs chan int
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func worker(s *S) {
   for i := range s.chs {
      println("In worker, ch = ", i)
   }

   wg.Done()
}

func main() {
   s := S{make(chan int)}

   runtime.SetFinalizer(&s, func(ss *S) {
      println("Finalizer")
      close(ss.chs)
   })


   wg.Add(1)

   go worker(&s)
   for i := 0; i < 1; i++ {
      s.chs <- 1
   }

   runtime.GC()

   wg.Wait()
}
```

Output (go 1.8.3):

> In worker, ch =  1
>
> Finalizer

---

I expect this program to deadlock. `runtime.GC()` will not collect `s`, since `worker()` holds a reference to `s.chs`.

However it terminates with go 1.8.3. In the finalizer of `s`, even `close(s.chs)` is called successfully.

I wonder if it has something special do with `range` and GC.

Thanks very much.

Comment: The range keyword isn't special in that way, it's just that the compiler optimizations made can determine that `s` will not be used again. Make `s` global and it will deadlock.

Comment: Just in case you're not merely experimenting but are instead trying to implement "destructors", I have to warn you—please don't! Idiomatic Go custom types should provide explicit "resource deallocation/freeing" methods, such as `Close()` on types which wrap FDs and sockets. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32768243/720999).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what is going on, but from the `runtime` godoc, second to last paragraph for [`SetFinalizer`](https://godoc.org/runtime#SetFinalizer):

> For example, if p points to a struct that contains a file descriptor
>   d, and p has a finalizer that closes that file descriptor, and if the
>   last use of p in a function is a call to syscall.Write(p.d, buf,
>   size), then p may be unreachable as soon as the program enters
>   syscall.Write. The finalizer may run at that moment, closing p.d,
>   causing syscall.Write to fail because it is writing to a closed file
>   descriptor (or, worse, to an entirely different file descriptor opened
>   by a different goroutine). To avoid this problem, call
>   runtime.KeepAlive(p) after the call to syscall.Write.

Which suggests to me that the `Finalizer` can possibly run as early as immediately after the last usage of the `var` in question.

I've never thought of this possibility myself, but technically, the GC would be able to know if it could collect a variable long before the variable's scope is gone. Consider this simplistic example.

```
func main() {
    str := "Hello World"
    fmt.Println(str)
    someMainLoop()
    // nothing after this, but someMainLoop() continues until stopped manually
}
```

There is no reason why `str` couldn't be collected by the GC. It is never used again, and it is very possible it knows this.

Comment: yes, the SSA compiler backend makes it so variables can "go out of scope" almost immediately after their use, since it's much easier to determine when something is no longer used. I guarantee this example will fail with an older compiler like go1.6.

Comment: @JimB Yes, this example will fail with go 1.7.